# Python code to convert Integer into Binary

Tags: python, binary, integer

I need a code in Python 3.3 to convert an integer into binary.
This is my first try:

```
a = input(str("Please Enter a Number")
if a == float:
    print (1)
else print(0)
b = a/2
while True:
    if b == float:
        print(1)
    else print(0)
```

I don't know why I keep getting errors with the `if a == float:`.
And I know that the rest of the code is wrong too, but this `:` makes me crazy.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with "if a == float:"?

Comment: What is float in this case?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish with your while loop?

Comment: John, welcome to Stack Overflow. I notice that your post does not include a question. Maybe you are asking "How do I convert integer to binary?" Or maybe you are asking "why doesn't `a == float` do what I want?" Since you didn't ask a question, it is hard to know which question to answer. Please edit your post to include a specific question.

Comment: Are we not going to point out all the syntax errors?

Comment: Nah, I try to complain about only one thing at a time, particularly with new members. I haven't figured out how to say "[ENOQUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/about)" and "http://SSCCE.ORG" in one breath.

Comment: I wrote a gist that does kinda what I think John is trying to do. John, check it out: https://gist.github.com/camerazn/7222436

Comment: Do you want an answer in raw loops?

Answer (score 11):

Your code has a lot of issues:

1. Your indentation is off.  Indentation is very important in Python since that is how it knows what goes with what.
2. You need to use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) to see if an object is a float.  I assume this is what you are trying to do with `a == float`.  But, that doesn't make sense because, in Python 3.x., `input` always returns a string object.  So, `a` is a string. However, if `float` is actually a variable, then you should change its name.  Naming a variable `float` is a bad practice since it overrides the built-in.
3. You are missing a colon at the end of each `else`.
4. You are missing a closing parenthesis on the first line.
5. The `str` in the first line is unnecessary (not an error, but I just thought I'd mention it).

However, instead of fixing all this, I'm going to introduce you to the [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bin) built-in:

```
>>> n = 127
>>> bin(n)
>>> # The "0b" at the start means "binary".
'0b1111111'
>>> # This gets rid of the "0b"
>>> bin(n)[2:]
'1111111'
>>>
```

It was built explicitly to do what you are trying to do.

Also, here are some references on Python you might enjoy:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm

http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: Not to mention there's a missing closing parenthesis on the first line.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `a == float` is a type test. He might actually have a variable named `float`.

Comment: Yea, I don't know precisely either.  Let me amend my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `bin` function:

```
>>> bin(100)
'0b1100100'
```

Ignore the `0b` infront of the string. You can always get the raw binary numbers using using `bin(your_numer)[2:]`.

Also, you can get this using the `format` function:

```
>>> format(100, 'b')
'1100100'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print it in binary you can just do:
    print(bin(a))

Answer (score 0):

This is what i made

```
while True:
    print("FIND OUT WHAT BINARY THIS IS")
    space = " "
    num1 = int(input())
    while num1 > 0:
        if num1 % 2 == 0:
          space = space + "0"
        else:
          space = space + "1"
        num1 = int(num1 / 2)
    else:
     space = space[::-1]
     print(space)
```